# Yesod - Monad Forms with Pagination, or even Input Forms with Pagination, is there an optimal way to implement it

Tags: forms, haskell, get, yesod, web-development-server

How can I use a Monad Form or even an Input Form to pass variables of a GET request and also navigate through its pages?

Comment: I think one usually does not use a form for pagination, but constructs a URI with a querystring at the end.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem could you create any snippet in Haskell using the Yesod framework just to illustrate this way? I can imagine that it is right because the querystring will contain all the filters but I don't know the "official" or "optimal" way of implementing such links.